# Unable to install tensorflow on Win10 - ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

Trying to run `import tensorflow as tf` but it failed.
I just installed tensorflow but is not allowing to import it.

This is the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>()
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    242         else:
--> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
    344 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-64156d691fe5> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     25 
     26 from tensorflow._api.v1 import app

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>()
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AMartinez147\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\AMartinez147\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\AMartinez147\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\AMartinez147\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\AMartinez147\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

this is the `pip list`

```
Package                            Version   
---------------------------------- ----------
absl-py                            0.7.1     
alabaster                          0.7.11    
altair                             2.2.2     
anaconda-client                    1.7.2     
anaconda-navigator                 1.9.6     
anaconda-project                   0.8.2     
aniso8601                          5.1.0     
appdirs                            1.4.3     
asn1crypto                         0.24.0    
astor                              0.7.1     
astroid                            2.0.4     
astropy                            3.0.4     
atomicwrites                       1.2.1     
attrs                              18.2.0    
Automat                            0.7.0     
Babel                              2.6.0     
backcall                           0.1.0     
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size 1.0.0     
beautifulsoup4                     4.6.3     
bitarray                           0.8.3     
bkcharts                           0.2       
blaze                              0.11.3    
bleach                             2.1.4     
bokeh                              0.13.0    
boto                               2.49.0    
Bottleneck                         1.2.1     
branca                             0.3.0     
category-encoders                  1.3.0     
certifi                            2018.11.29
cffi                               1.11.5    
chardet                            3.0.4     
click                              6.7       
cloudpickle                        0.5.5     
clyent                             1.2.2     
colorama                           0.3.9     
colorlover                         0.3.0     
comtypes                           1.1.7     
conda                              4.6.7     
conda-build                        3.15.1    
constantly                         15.1.0    
contextlib2                        0.5.5     
cryptography                       2.4.2     
cufflinks                          0.14.6    
cycler                             0.10.0    
Cython                             0.28.5    
cytoolz                            0.9.0.1   
dash                               0.29.0    
dash-core-components               0.37.1    
dash-html-components               0.13.2    
dash-renderer                      0.14.3    
dask                               0.19.1    
datashape                          0.5.4     
decorator                          4.3.0     
defusedxml                         0.5.0     
distributed                        1.23.1    
docopt                             0.6.2     
docutils                           0.14      
entrypoints                        0.2.3     
et-xmlfile                         1.0.1     
fastcache                          1.0.2     
filelock                           3.0.8     
Flask                              1.0.2     
Flask-Compress                     1.4.0     
Flask-Cors                         3.0.6     
flask-restplus                     0.12.1    
folium                             0.6.0     
gast                               0.2.2     
geographiclib                      1.49      
geopy                              1.17.0    
gevent                             1.3.6     
glob2                              0.6       
greenlet                           0.4.15    
grpcio                             1.20.1    
h5py                               2.8.0     
heapdict                           1.0.0     
html5lib                           1.0.1     
hyperlink                          18.0.0    
idna                               2.7       
imageio                            2.4.1     
imagesize                          1.1.0     
imbalanced-learn                   0.4.3     
incremental                        17.5.0    
ipykernel                          4.10.0    
ipython                            6.5.0     
ipython-genutils                   0.2.0     
ipywidgets                         7.4.1     
isort                              4.3.4     
itsdangerous                       0.24      
jdcal                              1.4       
jedi                               0.12.1    
Jinja2                             2.10      
jsonschema                         2.6.0     
jupyter                            1.0.0     
jupyter-client                     5.2.3     
jupyter-console                    5.2.0     
jupyter-core                       4.4.0     
jupyterlab                         0.34.9    
jupyterlab-launcher                0.13.1    
jupyterthemes                      0.20.0    
Keras-Applications                 1.0.7     
Keras-Preprocessing                1.0.9     
keyring                            13.2.1    
kiwisolver                         1.0.1     
lazy-object-proxy                  1.3.1     
lesscpy                            0.13.0    
llvmlite                           0.24.0    
locket                             0.2.0     
lxml                               4.2.5     
Markdown                           3.1       
MarkupSafe                         1.0       
matplotlib                         2.2.3     
mccabe                             0.6.1     
memory-profiler                    0.55.0    
menuinst                           1.4.14    
mistune                            0.8.3     
mkl-fft                            1.0.10    
mkl-random                         1.0.2     
mock                               2.0.0     
more-itertools                     4.3.0     
mpmath                             1.0.0     
msgpack                            0.5.6     
multipledispatch                   0.6.0     
navigator-updater                  0.2.1     
nbconvert                          5.4.0     
nbformat                           4.4.0     
networkx                           2.1       
nltk                               3.3       
nose                               1.3.7     
notebook                           5.6.0     
num2words                          0.5.9     
numba                              0.39.0    
numexpr                            2.6.8     
numpy                              1.15.4    
numpydoc                           0.8.0     
odo                                0.5.1     
olefile                            0.46      
openpyxl                           2.5.6     
packaging                          17.1      
pandas                             0.23.4    
pandocfilters                      1.4.2     
parso                              0.3.1     
partd                              0.3.8     
path.py                            11.1.0    
pathlib2                           2.3.2     
patsy                              0.5.0     
pbr                                5.2.0     
pep8                               1.7.1     
pickleshare                        0.7.4     
Pillow                             5.2.0     
pip                                19.1      
pkginfo                            1.4.2     
plotly                             3.3.0     
pluggy                             0.7.1     
ply                                3.11      
prometheus-client                  0.3.1     
prompt-toolkit                     1.0.15    
protobuf                           3.7.1     
psutil                             5.4.7     
py                                 1.6.0     
pyasn1                             0.4.4     
pyasn1-modules                     0.2.2     
pycodestyle                        2.4.0     
pycosat                            0.6.3     
pycparser                          2.18      
pycrypto                           2.6.1     
pycurl                             7.43.0.2  
pyflakes                           2.0.0     
Pygments                           2.2.0     
pylint                             2.1.1     
pyodbc                             4.0.24    
pyOpenSSL                          18.0.0    
pyparsing                          2.2.0     
PySocks                            1.6.8     
pytest                             3.8.0     
pytest-arraydiff                   0.2       
pytest-astropy                     0.4.0     
pytest-doctestplus                 0.1.3     
pytest-openfiles                   0.3.0     
pytest-remotedata                  0.3.0     
python-dateutil                    2.7.3     
pytz                               2018.5    
PyWavelets                         1.0.0     
pywin32                            223       
pywinpty                           0.5.4     
PyYAML                             3.13      
pyzmq                              17.1.2    
QtAwesome                          0.4.4     
qtconsole                          4.4.1     
QtPy                               1.5.0     
relativetimebuilder                0.2.0     
requests                           2.19.1    
retrying                           1.3.3     
rope                               0.11.0    
ruamel-yaml                        0.15.46   
scikit-image                       0.14.0    
scikit-learn                       0.20.3    
scipy                              1.1.0     
seaborn                            0.9.0     
Send2Trash                         1.5.0     
service-identity                   17.0.0    
setuptools                         40.2.0    
simplegeneric                      0.8.1     
singledispatch                     3.4.0.3   
six                                1.11.0    
snowballstemmer                    1.2.1     
sortedcollections                  1.0.1     
sortedcontainers                   2.0.5     
Sphinx                             1.7.9     
sphinxcontrib-websupport           1.1.0     
spyder                             3.3.1     
spyder-kernels                     0.2.6     
SQLAlchemy                         1.2.11    
statsmodels                        0.9.0     
sympy                              1.1.1     
tables                             3.4.4     
tblib                              1.3.2     
tensorboard                        1.13.1    
tensorflow                         1.13.1    
tensorflow-estimator               1.13.0    
tensorflow-gpu                     1.13.1    
termcolor                          1.1.0     
terminado                          0.8.1     
testpath                           0.3.1     
textdistance                       4.1.2     
toolz                              0.9.0     
tornado                            5.1       
tqdm                               4.26.0    
traitlets                          4.3.2     
Twisted                            18.7.0    
unicodecsv                         0.14.1    
urllib3                            1.23      
vincent                            0.4.4     
wcwidth                            0.1.7     
webencodings                       0.5.1     
Werkzeug                           0.14.1    
wheel                              0.31.1    
widgetsnbextension                 3.4.1     
win-inet-pton                      1.0.1     
win-unicode-console                0.5       
wincertstore                       0.2       
wrapt                              1.10.11   
xgboost                            0.82      
xlrd                               1.1.0     
XlsxWriter                         1.1.0     
xlwings                            0.11.8    
xlwt                               1.3.0     
zict                               0.1.3     
zope.interface                     4.5.0
```

Comment: How old is your Anaconda installation that you still have the Continuum version?  You may want to consider uninstalling and reinstalling with the most recent version

Comment: Are you running from the conda prompt?  My guess is this is a path issue if you can import tensorflow from invoking python at the conda prompt but cannot otherwise get tensorflow to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the diagnosis steps that suggested on this post:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11065

The easiest way could be as below:

> After searching a lot and trying to install and reinstall Python, i found the solution was very simple
>    use the following for windows
>    `python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl`

You should update the url from this link based on your OS and python version:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package-location

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I installed tensorflow-cpu through anaconda navigator and got the same error. Reinstalling through pip works.